# Rosserial Arduino Problem

Tags: arduino, rosserial, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i just started using ROS and i'm trying to use rosserial_arduino.
I'm trying to get the examples working but I have some problems, when I launch:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0
```

I have this error on the console:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1402855665.112426] Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

I read other threads and i loaded the sketch on a Mega 2650 and a UNO with atmega328 to exclude memory issues but i have always the same error.

Some additional information:

```
$rospack find rosserial
[rospack] Error: stack/package rosserial not found

$rospack find rosserial_arduino
/opt/ros/hydro/share/rosserial_arduino

$rospack find rosserial_python
/opt/ros/hydro/share/rosserial_python

$rosmsg show Adc
[rosserial_arduino/Adc]:
uint16 adc0
uint16 adc1
uint16 adc2
uint16 adc3
uint16 adc4
uint16 adc5
```

I'm running Hydro on Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit

Any help would be appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173688/rosserial-arduino-problem/) by [Wedontplay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18883/wedontplay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2014-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think you're specifying the port parameter to the rosserial_python node properly.

Try specifying the ROS `~port` parameter:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wedontplay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18883/wedontplay/) on 2014-07-11**:
Tx for the answer and sorry for the late reply. Actually it was a trivial problem related to the fact i was running ubuntu on a virtual machine and arduino program had some problems handling the serial port itself.

**Comment by [BigAnt](https://answers.ros.org/users/40240/bigant/) on 2019-02-27**:
Can you specify the solution, because I have the same problem.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-02-27**:
@BigAnt please ask a new question instead of commenting on a 5-year-old question.